# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.vinay.patients.config.AppConfig: Unsatisfied

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, hsqldb, spring-4

I am new with Spring 4 framework trying to get string from the embedded HyperSQL 
 database in eclipse sfs but getting this error of Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.vinay.patients.config.AppConfig.

errorlogs:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.vinay.patients.config.AppConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.vinay.patients.config;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vinay.patients")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    // @Bean
    // public DataSource getDataSource() {
    // DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    // dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/healthcare");
    // dataSource.setUsername("root");
    // dataSource.setPassword("root");
    // return dataSource;
    // }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(String string, String string2, String string3, String string4) throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver"); // you can call your code here
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."); // to get these configuration values
        ds.setUsername("sa");
        ds.setPassword("");
        return dataSource(ds.getUsername(),ds.getPassword(),ds.getUrl(),ds.getDriverClassName());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}


AppInitializer.java


public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

PatientNameService.java

```
package com.vinay.patients.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import com.vinay.patients.db.PatientDAO;
import com.vinay.patients.config.AppConfig;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vinay.patients")
public class PatientNameService{
    @Autowired
    static AppConfig appConfig;
    static PatientDAO dao;

    public String getDocall() throws SQLException{
        ApplicationContext context;
        String Query ="";
        String username="";
        String password="";
        String url="";
        String classname ="";
        String doc_name="";
        Connection con = null;
        Statement  stmt = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        //using config class to call the bean and collecting all the required parameters.
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        DataSource dataSource = context.getBean(DataSource.class);
        Query = dao.getDocList();
        appConfig.dataSource(username, password, url,classname);
        try {
            Class.forName(classname);
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(username,password,url);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            result = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
            while(result.next()){
                doc_name= result.getString("Doc_Name").toString();
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
         }
        return doc_name;
    }
}
```

controller.java

```
 package com.vinay.patients.controller;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.vinay.patients.service.PatientNameService;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    static PatientNameService PNservice ;
  /*  @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Viney Dhiman");
        return "welcome";
    }
    */

    @RequestMapping(value="/ViewDoc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String data(Model model) throws SQLException {
        String all_Doc = PNservice.getDocall().toString();
        model.addAttribute("name", all_Doc);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vinay.patients</groupId>
    <artifactId>Evidhi</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Evidhi Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Evidhi</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: First stop mixing spring versions you are mixing 4.3 and 3.2 jars never mix versions of a framework (regardless of the framework). You are creating a datasource with a lot of String values but there are no `String` beans. Yu need to annotate those `String` parameter with `@Value` to have the corresponding property value injected, else it will simply fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is flawed in multiple ways.

1. Never create an `ApplicationContext` because you need a bean, well that is unless you want to run in memory, transaction and hard to debug issues.
2. You are creating a `DataSource` based on a lot of `String` parameters but omit the `@Value` on those method arguments
3. Something is either a `@Configuration` or `@Component` not both.
4. You are mixing Spring Versions 4.3 and 3.2 jars (never mix versions of any framework).

### Mixing Spring Version

In your pom you have defined a property `org.springframework-version` use that for all `org.springframework` dependencies to have consistent versions. So use that for your `spring-jdbc` dependency as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

### Don't create an `ApplicationContext`

In your code you are doing a lot of things, creating a context, manually load jdbc drivers etc. etc. don't do any of those. In your service you should inject your `DataSource` or maybe even better a `JdbcTemplate`.

```
@Service
public class PatientNameService{

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public PatientNameService(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc=jdbc;
    }

    public String getDocall() throws SQLException{
        return jdbc.queryForString(<your-query-here>);
    }
}
```

There is no creating of an `ApplicationContext`, no `DataSource` lookup yourself etc. It is now also a `@Service` and not a mix and match of thins.

### Use `@Value` or the `Environment` to get properties

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(String string, String string2, String string3, String string4) throws SQLException { ... }
```

This signature is telling Spring to create a `DataSource` and that for the creation it needs to lookup 5 beans of the type `String` the exception you get indicates you don't have those beans (which isn't that strange because the probably are in a property file loaded with `@PropertySource` if not they should.

Now you can annotate all those method arguments with `@Value(...)` and specify the name or retrieve them using the `Environment`. The latter is easier when using a lot of properties.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vinay.patients")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName");
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"); 
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password");
        return ds; 
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Notice the `@PropertySource` this expects an `application.properties` in the root of your class path (i.e. `src/main/resources` containing the 4 properties needed to construct the `DataSource`.

Also notice the removal of the `@Component` there is already a `@Configuration` which does the same and more.

Comment: Thank you so much for important tips. I will surely follow them in future
, catch you soon if i got any new query. ....peace...  @M. Deinum

Comment: I have one more question can i do it without using or creating the .properties file under the resource folder. (or by directly declaring the bean in Appconfig.java file ). @M.Denium.

Comment: You stated you want those configurable, if you hardcode them how will you change them.

Answer (score 0):

you can create DataSource by importing -> org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource; and in database configuration use like below

```
private final static String URL_PATH = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_pgs=true";//test is your db name
private final static String USER_NAME = "sa";
private final static String PASS_WORD = "";

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public JDBCDataSource getDataSource() {
    JDBCDataSource dataSource = new JDBCDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(URL_PATH);
    dataSource.setUser(USER_NAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(PASS_WORD);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: thank you for response but i need to ask do i have to mention this datasource configuration in the Appintializer.class ?

Comment: Appintializer class  mainly for dispatcher servlet, so use AppConfig class  or create separate file like DbConfig.java and mark it as @Configuration or import it into AppConfig.java

Comment: Its still not working datasource.seturl() is not showing in the options only setuser and setpassword is available.